# Startup script is not running

Tags: boot, command-line, bash, 20.04, startup

I am using Ubuntu 20.04LTS and I'm trying to run a script at startup. I created it in /etc/init.d/, gave it chmod 755 and ran the update-rc.d  defaults command but the program is not executed on my next boot.Here is my script

```
#!/bin/sh -e
#
# rc.local
#
# This script is executed at the end of each multiuser runlevel.
# Make sure that the script will "exit 0" on success or any other
# value on error.
#
# In order to enable or disable this script just change the execution
# bits.
#
# By default this script does nothing.

sudo /opt/lampp/lampp start
google-chrome
code

echo "Script run successfully"



exit 0
```

When i try to run the script directly

```
sudo service myscript.sh start
```

I get this message

```
● myscript.service
     Loaded: loaded (/etc/init.d/myscript.sh; generated)
     Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Sat 2020-07-18 14:00:39 +06; 3min 31s ago
       Docs: man:systemd-sysv-generator(8)
    Process: 12057 ExecStart=/etc/init.d/myscript.sh start (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
      Tasks: 39 (limit: 9344)
     Memory: 126.7M
     CGroup: /system.slice/myscript.service
             ├─12112 /opt/lampp/bin/httpd -k start -E /opt/lampp/logs/error_log -DSSL -DPHP
             ├─12117 /opt/lampp/bin/httpd -k start -E /opt/lampp/logs/error_log -DSSL -DPHP
             ├─12209 /bin/sh /opt/lampp/bin/mysqld_safe --datadir=/opt/lampp/var/mysql --pid-file=/opt/lampp/var/mysql/GraceHopper.pid
             ├─12226 /opt/lampp/bin/httpd -k start -E /opt/lampp/logs/error_log -DSSL -DPHP
             ├─12227 /opt/lampp/bin/httpd -k start -E /opt/lampp/logs/error_log -DSSL -DPHP
             ├─12228 /opt/lampp/bin/httpd -k start -E /opt/lampp/logs/error_log -DSSL -DPHP
             ├─12229 /opt/lampp/bin/httpd -k start -E /opt/lampp/logs/error_log -DSSL -DPHP
             ├─12230 /opt/lampp/bin/httpd -k start -E /opt/lampp/logs/error_log -DSSL -DPHP
             └─12358 /opt/lampp/sbin/mysqld --basedir=/opt/lampp --datadir=/opt/lampp/var/mysql --plugin-dir=/opt/lampp/lib/mysql/plugin/ --user=mysql --log-error=/opt/lampp/var/mysql/GraceHopper.err --pid-file=/opt/lampp/var/mysql/GraceHopper.pid --socket=/opt/lampp/var/mysql/mysql.sock --port=3306

Jul 18 14:00:39 GraceHopper myscript.sh[12113]: XAMP
Jul 18 14:00:39 GraceHopper myscript.sh[12080]: XAMP
Jul 18 14:00:39 GraceHopper myscript.sh[12080]: AMPP: Starting MySQ
Jul 18 14:00:39 GraceHopper sudo[12058]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session closed for user root
Jul 18 14:00:39 GraceHopper myscript.sh[12124]: AMPP
Jul 18 14:00:39 GraceHopper myscript.sh[12131]: AMPP
Jul 18 14:00:39 GraceHopper systemd[1]: myscript.service: Control process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Jul 18 14:00:39 GraceHopper systemd[1]: myscript.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Jul 18 14:00:39 GraceHopper systemd[1]: Failed to start myscript.service.
Jul 18 14:00:41 GraceHopper myscript.sh[12131]: 12125:12125:0718/140039.216854:ERROR:zygote_host_impl_linux.cc(89)] Running as root without --no-sandbox is not supported. See https://crbug.com/6381
```

Answer (score 0):

`/etc/rc.local` runs, as `root` (so your `sudo` is useless), at system startup.

This is before you login, and before the X server has been started, so `chrome` has no display to display on.

This belongs in `$HOME/.config/autostart`.

Comment: i have remove the sudo and remove the line which involve starting google chrome but the script is still not running